# Passing a destination to Maps and navigate to that point

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using react-native-maps in my React Native app and I have my MapView with some Markers on it.

What I'm trying to do is to open the default Maps app (so Maps in iOS and Google Maps in Android) when pressing on one Marker and pass the coordinates for navigating to that point (= setting the coordinates as the destination, see image below).
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmq4Z.jpg)

Right now the best way I found is to open the browser with something like this: `Linking.openURL('http://maps.google.com/maps?q=37.78825,-122.4324')` and then open Maps from the browser, but I'd like to avoid the browser because it seems a redundant step.
I also tried `Linking.openURL("geo:37.484847,-122.148386")` but this way Maps just opens at that coordinates, doesn't get them as the destination to navigate to.

I googled for at least a couple of hours to find a direct App -> Maps way but I still don't have a solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS here is the sample code

```
direction = 'http://maps.apple.com/?address=[youraddress]'
```

Check [This Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html).

Using React-Native version: 16.0.0-alpha.12

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link! 
After a long search I did manage to find the answer and ended up using an equivalent format, that is `http://maps.apple.com/?ll=[latitude],[longitude]`.